# Javascript dropdownlist doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The form is already hidden at the beginning. When I select Window, the form should become visible but it doesn't. I tried to add an if-else statement, if nothing it match it will show alert but that doesn't work either. I am guess it never fire. Any know know why?

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" Runat="Server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DropDownlistOptions() {
        var dropdownlist = document.getElementById("DropDownListForm");
        var selected = dropdownlist.options[dropdownlist.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selected == "Window") {
            document.getElementById("WindowForm").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            alert("failed");
        }
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content1" Runat="Server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListForm" runat="server" onchange="DropDownlistOptions()">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Window</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Linux</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<div id="WindowForm" style="visibility:hidden;">
    Form info to fill.....
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I just need to add

```
document.getElementById("<%=DropDownListForm.ClientID%>");
```